# autogenerate jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, code-generation

We all use and like that to handle click event for button we can just click it and write a handler with server code in C# or vb.net.

But if we want to handle client event, javascript comes for help. And I wonder, how can we add designer ability to generate client handlers with javascript or some popular library like jquery.

So how I see it in perfect world, I'm selecting the button in designer, go to it's properties, then choose events like hover, enter or click and have a handler function in which I can write my code to handle it.

So the question is - how can it be done, to make this ability to autogenerate this empty function and make sure it will handle the exact event I need? I know how to handle this events in javascript, but this way seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: Are you talking about an IDE for jQuery?

Comment: Not for jquery, but for any js code inside asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft's Glimmer](http://visitmix.com/labs/glimmer/) writes jQuery. They also have a nice demo video on their frontpage. Glimmer is free, by the way.

Comment: Yes, thanks for answer! Glimmer is really a great thing. But you`ll need to merge the code with VS and asp.net as it generates html+css, no asp.net. So it would be nice to do something almost the same, but for visual studio and asp.net.